# What is the significance of Deep Amavasya?

Tags: rituals, festivals, amavasya

Today is Deep Amavasya and many people in Maharashtra worship and light up diyas or earthen lamps in their homes at night. I want to know what is the significance of this festival and what are the ceremonies to be performed in it?